# Is there a limit to how much files can be uploaded with one file input

Tags: php, file-upload

I have one file input tag which has the multiple attribute. If i select 10 files on the php backend the $_FILES array is always length of 5. 
phpinfo() says that max_file_uploads is 20.Is this a php or js limit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a limit imposed by PHP.  You will need to configure the php.ini file.  Check out http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a number of configurations for file uploads and form data, which can be configured in the php.ini. For more information regarding the ones specific to file uploads, have a look at
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads